# Unexpected token `export` after webpack ts-loader for DropdownTreeviewModule

Tags: angular, webpack, ecmascript-6, webpack-dev-server, typescript2.1

I've tried to inlude anular2 [treeview](https://github.com/leovo2708/ng2-dropdown-treeview) module into my test application, but getting the error unexpected token

> 'export * from '....//filepath.....' in my bundle.js

I know it's an issue of transpiling typescript file to js, but I'm only getting this error into this particular treeview module.

I've tried both `ts-loader` and `babel`, but not working.

**Below is my webpack config.**

```
var WriteFilePlugin = require('write-file-webpack-plugin');
var path = require("path");

var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "app");
var config = {
    entry: path.resolve(APP_DIR + "/main.ts"),
    output: {
        path: APP_DIR,
        publicPath: "/app/",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    watch: true,
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', ".web.js", ".ts", ".js", ".jsx"]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader:"babel!ts-loader",
                //loader:"ts-loader", // tried this also
                exclude: "node_modules"
            }
        ]
    }
}
module.exports = config;
```

**and tsconfig:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6", //(also tried with "target:es5")
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
  ],
  "types": [
    "core-js",
    "hammerjs",
    "lodash"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

My all other imported and created modules are working, except this one.

Let me know, what I'm missing here? Thanks

Comment: Usualy it happens when you import a module that you shouldn't I already experienced that when importing some random private angular modules instead of importing from barrel files (eg `import {Something} from "angular/core/some/stupid/things"` instead of `import {Something} from "angular/core"`).

Comment: @n00dl3: I've followed exact steps, and tried to load module from main file, but It seems to be issue with node module itself. all js are in es6.

Comment: Ow... I experienced this also -with ng2-translate-, this is what I have done as a workaround in my webpack config : `{ test: /ng2-translate(?:\/|\\).*\.js$/, loader: babel-loader", query: { "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"] } }` note that I targeted the module's js files specifically (they are not ts, they are js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried few es6 loaders to mitigate the transpiling issue, but actually issue was with exported library itself. So below 1 line solved my problem.

`import {DropdownTreeviewModule} from 'ng2-dropdown-treeview/bundles/ng2-dropdown-treeview.umd';`

rather than importing module from `ng2-dropdown-treeview`, I have to import it from bundled file.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same kind of trouble using ng2-translate.

In my webpack config file I targetted the js files in the module, and loaded those files with the babel-loader, applying the `transform-es2015-modules-commonjs` plugin. You will need to change the `test` part to match the treeview module path:

```
{
  test: /ng2-translate(?:\/|\\).*\.js$/,
  loader: "babel-loader",
  query: {
    "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
  }
}
```

Note that only `js` files are targeted, because you don't really import `ts` files, just using definitions for the ts compiler.

Also note that I have made this change too but I don't remember why exactly, I guess it might have broken the sourcemap :

```
{
  // basically this enable source-mapping for everything except this module
  test: /(?:(?!ng2-translate(?:\/|\\).*))\.js$/,
  loaders: ["source-map-loader"]
},
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and time (+upvote), you're right in your context but in my case problem was with exported library itself, no loaders could correct it. [and I've already tried your solution :- ) ], So I've posted my solution as my answer.

Comment: glad you found a solution. ;)